# JavaScript Selector is Not working when condition changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I am facing an issue with JavaScript Selector here is the code

```
onChangeCustomGroup : function(){
    var element = this.model.get("customGroup"),
        that = this;

    if(element == "SECURITY") {
        that.ui.__el_string_Abc.xyzSelector();
    }

    if(element == "BENCHMARK") {
        that.ui.__el_string_Abc.dfgSelector();
    }
}
```

onChangeCustomGroup is a ModelEvent in Backbone 
There are two fields 1.customGroup
                     2. filterCode
customgroup field having two values populate 1.SECURITY AND 2.BENCHMARK

securitySelector and benchmarkSelector are two functions which will returns a set of values in the form of html and appends with the filtercode region

The issue is here when i select SECURITY ,security fields are populating in the filtercode field but on change to BENCHMARK benchmark selector is not populating 
It is something like working only with one condition.Not with two

Comment: does the `benchmarkSelector()` method get called ? If so, the problem may be that function itself

Comment: Could you post both functions - `benchmarkSelector` and `securitySelector`?

Comment: @user3247425 If this issue has been resolved you should post the solution that solved it and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Each time when i cal the function i call another method before the condition which destruct the existing Selector    ,A custom method.Thnk you